# Запуск проекта Libgdx в AndroidStudio

Tags: android-studio, исключения, gradle

Решил заняться разработкой игр при помощи фреймворка libgdx и сразу же столкнулся с двумя проблемами:

1. При первом импортировании сгенерированного проекта в андроид студио и запуске на десктопной версии выдало следующие ошибки -

   > Could not resolve all files for configuration :classpath.
   >   Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
2. После поиска в интернете нашел решение проблемы, указав google() в репозиториях, но выскочили следующие проблемы :

   > java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/badlogic/gdx/ApplicationListener
   >
   > Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
   >
   > Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
   >   Exception in thread "main" 
   >   Process finished with exit code 1

Находил в интернете, что то про разность скомпилированных классов и запускаемых , но не понял как решить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Теперь полностью решено. Решение выше помогает, однако апк файл не билдиться.
Для того, чтобы запустить десктоп и андроид версии в среде 3.0.1 и при версии градл 4 и более, необходимо указать в андроид студио, чтобы она запускала Jar-aplication, а не десктоп.

1. Создаете jar-aplication
2. Path to jar указываете из своего проекта
3. рабочая дирректория также из своего проекта android/assets
4. модуль десктоп
5. и создаете градл таск как на рисунке

У меня все заработало.
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/4698
Нашел решение здесь, если не поймете мое.

[image: Все указано на рисунке]

Comment: Оказалось, для того, чтобы появилась папка libs в desktop, необходимо (по крайней мере я так сделал) : сначала сгенерировать проект, импортировать проект (НО НЕ ОБНОВЛЯТЬ ВЕРСИЮ ГРАДЛ), создать desktop aplication, создать jar-aplictaion про которую я говорил выше, после этого можно обновлять.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, не уверен на сколько это правильно, но это решило мою проблему : в старой версии андроид студио и гридл были ошибки как раз в репозиториях. При запуске проекта, иср предлагает обновить градл, дабы исправить это. Я не стал обновлять - в итоге все работает.